# WordPress title tag change with plugin

Tags: wordpress, plugins

I'm plugin writing, I want change header.php **title** tag,

How can I do it?

Thanks!

Comment: What you've tried so far?

Comment: wp_title function don't work :/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wp_title` has deprecated since version 4.4. So, we should use the new filter `pre_get_document_title`. Try the following code.

```
add_filter('pre_get_document_title', 'change_title');
function change_title($title) {
   return 'My Custom Title';
}
```

See details about this hook https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/hooks/pre_get_document_title/

Comment: It's worked, thank you so much :)